# Why do I get -2 reputation for 'Development tool access by class name undefined'?

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday I got -2 reputation for something that looks like an internal error message to me. It says:

> Development tool access by class name undefined

[image: -2 reputation with message 'Development tool access by class name undefined']

What does that mean? Is that a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[You had edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4396407) [an answer (10k link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22565158/103167), which is now deleted causing you to lose the +2 reputation associated with the edit.

In other cases, -2 reputation can occur when the bonus for accepting an answer is lost due to deletion of the question.

It's not unusual for a question title to resemble an error message, but I suspect you're more likely to remember the title of a question you asked yourself, vs one you edited.

Comment: Oops, of course. I accidentally interpreted the question title as explanation for why I got the negative reputation. Non-the-less the reason should be made more obvious than just saying 'removed'. Especially people with less than 10k reputation can't get a link to the deleted page.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: Did you try hoovering over it? There you get a few more words...

Comment: Yes, it says 'post was removed'.